# Trigger/Untrigger events on radio buttons with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form in HTML with radio buttons

```
<input type="radio" name="quiz" value="University" onclick="openUniversity()">University<br>
<p id="uniquestion" style="display: none;">Please tell us your University:</p>
<input id="unifield" type="text" name="uniquestion" style="display: none;"/>
<input type="radio" name="quiz" value="Other" onclick="openOther()">Other<br>
<p id="othquestion" style="display: none;">Please specify source:</p>
<input id="othfield" type="text" name="othquestion" style="display: none;"/>
```

I need to display the text and input field once radio button is checked, and hide it back when unchecked (something else checked).

Here is the JavaScript i got so far:

```
function openUniversity() {
    document.getElementById("uniquestion").style.display = "inline";
    document.getElementById("unifield").style.display = "block";
}
function openOther() {
    document.getElementById("othquestion").style.display = "inline";
    document.getElementById("othfield").style.display = "block";
}
```

This "unhides" the blocks of code but does not hide it once deselected.
If anyone has a solution, I'd appreciate it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set display type as none on the previous field on the select of next field. I have added a code snippet where you can verify the same. However, I would suggest a better approach:

call only 1 function on radio change by using the onChange attribute, then use e.target.value to get currently selected value. Then display the field you want and set `display: none` for all the other fields recursively.

```js
function openUniversity() {
    document.getElementById("uniquestion").style.display = "inline";
    document.getElementById("unifield").style.display = "block";
    
    document.getElementById("othquestion").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("othfield").style.display = "none";
}
function openOther() {
    document.getElementById("othquestion").style.display = "inline";
    document.getElementById("othfield").style.display = "block";
    
    document.getElementById("uniquestion").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("unifield").style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="quiz" value="University" onclick="openUniversity()">University<br>
<p id="uniquestion" style="display: none;">Please tell us your University:</p>
<input id="unifield" type="text" name="uniquestion" style="display: none;"/>
<input type="radio" name="quiz" value="Other" onclick="openOther()">Other<br>
<p id="othquestion" style="display: none;">Please specify source:</p>
<input id="othfield" type="text" name="othquestion" style="display: none;"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need some modifications in both of your functions:

```
function openUniversity() {
    document.getElementById("uniquestion").style.display = "inline";
    document.getElementById("unifield").style.display = "block";


    // Added to hide other...
    document.getElementById("othquestion").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("othfield").style.display = "none";
}

function openOther() {
    document.getElementById("othquestion").style.display = "inline";
    document.getElementById("othfield").style.display = "block";


    // Added to hide uni...
    document.getElementById("uniquestion").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("unifield").style.display = "none";
}
```